# How to handle daily/weekly/mothly boards on AppEngine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm developing a high score web service for my game, and it's running on Google App Engine.

My game has 5 difficulties, so I originally had 5 boards with entries for each (player_login, score and time). If the player submitted a lower score than the previously scored, it got dismissed, so only the highest score is kept for each player.

But to add more fun into this, I'd decided to include daily/weekly/monthly/yearly high score tables. So I've created 5 boards for each difficulty, making it 25 boards. When a score is submitted, it's saved into each board, and the boards are supposed to be cleared on every day/week/month/year.

This happens by a cron job that is invoked and deletes all entries from a specific board.

Here comes the problem: it looks like deleting entries from the datastore is slow. From my test daily cleanups it looks like deleting a single entry takes around 200 ms.

In the worst-case scenario, if the game would be quite popular and would have, say, 100 000 players, and each of them would have an entry in the yearly board, it would take 100 000 * 0.012 seconds = 12 000 seconds (3 hours!!) to clear that board. I think we are allowed to have jobs of up to 30 seconds in App Engine, so this wouldn't work.

I'm deleting with [following code (thanks to Nick Johnson)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034327/google-app-engine-delete-until-count-0/3046960#3046960):

```
q = Score.all(keys_only=True).filter('b = ',boardToClear)
results = q.fetch(500)
  while results:
    self.response.out.write("deleting one batch;")
    db.delete(results)
    q = Score.all(keys_only=True).filter('b = ',boardToClear).with_cursor(q.cursor())
    results = q.fetch(500)
```

*What do you recommend me to do with this problem?*

One approach that comes to my mind is to use a task queue and delete older scores than that are permitted in each board, i.e. which have expired, but in smaller quantities. This way I wouldn't hit the CPU limit for one task, but the cleanup would not be (nearly) instantaneous, so my 12 000 seconds long cleanup would be split into 1 200 tasks, each roughly 10 seconds long.

But I think that there is something that I'm doing wrong, this kind of operation would be a lot faster when done in relational database. Possibly something is wrong with my approach to the datastore and scoring, because being locked in RDBMS mindset.

Comment: I've just figured out that I don't need all of the scores anyway, just top 100 or top 1000 or whatever. If the player hit score that is below top 1000, I'll just tell him that he ain't good enough to be in a top list, therefore he ain't good enough to use up my cpu time in adding and later deleting the score ;)

Comment: take a look at [this post and open source library](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/01/google-code-jams-ranking-library.html) from the google code jam team. they had the same problem and ended up developing a scalable scoreboard that handles both updates and requests for arbitrary pages efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a couple of small suggestions:

1. Does deletion take 200ms per item even when you delete items in a batch process? The fastest way to delete should be to do a `keys_only` query and then call `db.delete()` on an entire list of keys at once.
2. The 30-second limit was recently relaxed to 10 minutes for background work (like the cron jobs or queue tasks that you're contemplating) as of [1.4.0](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/12/happy-holidays-from-app-engine-team-140.html).

These may not fundamentally address your problem, though. I think there's no way to get around the fact that deleting a large number of records (hundreds of thousands, say), will take some time. I'm not sure that this is as big a problem for your use case though, as I can see a couple of techniques that would help.

1. As you suggest, use a task queue to split up a long-running tasks into several smaller tasks. Your use case (deleting a huge number of items that match a particular query) is ideal for a map-reduce task. Nick Johnson's [blog post on the Mapper API](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Exploring-the-new-mapper-API) may be very helpful for you (so that you don't have to write all of that task management code on your own).
2. Do you need to delete all the out-of-date board entries immediately? If you had a field that listed which week, month, or year that a particular entry counted for, you could index on that field and then only display entries from the current month on the visible leaderboard. (Disk space is cheap, after all.) And then if you wanted to slowly (over hours, say, instead of milliseconds) remove the out-of-date data, you could do that in the background without ever having incorrect data on your leaderboards.

Comment: I've tried batch delete now, and deleting 1000 items now took ms=2540 cpu_ms=214844 api_cpu_ms=213538. So still it's 200 ms for an item.

Comment: +1; use a field so you do not have to magically clear the board in milliseconds.

Comment: @Axarydax, that is quite a bit of CPU to delete a single item. Still, as Nick Johnson points out below, by batch deleting you're executing most of those in parallel, so you're not increasing latency that much. At that rate, you could delete almost a quarter million items in a single 10-minute call. (Of course, if what you're really worried about is the dollar cost of CPU time, that may be cold comfort.)

Comment: I've found out that I've had about 9 redundant indexes that were somehow generated during the development. Now deletion time per item is down to 130 ms.

Answer (score 3):

Delete entities in batches. Although a single delete takes a noticeable amount of time (though 200ms seems very high), batch deletes take no longer, as they delete all the entities in parallel. Task Queue and cron jobs can now run for up to 10 minutes, so timeouts should not be an issue.